# what's the difference between int (* f [])(); and int f[]();

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

i find this in *Pointers on C*

```
int f[]();  /* this one is illegal */
```

and:

```
int (* f [])(); /* this one legal. */
```

i really want know what's the usage of the second one.

thank you.

Comment: this same question was asked today look at this link for answer http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: Useful site for non-obvious declarations: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: You can't declare an array of function (since the memory taken up by a function is not known). You can only declare an array of pointer to function.

Comment: I actually don't see how the second is legal since the size of the function pointer array is not known.

Comment: ahya~ those are all quite weird

Comment: @BhavikShah link is quite good as an solution and self-explanatory too.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: You're quite right, it is illegal: http://ideone.com/JQMfw6

Comment: @lushl9301: What compiler are you using that allows you to compile `int (* f [])();`?

Comment: MinGW gcc on windows. try select the language as C instead of c++  http://ideone.com/fJaxl1 @j-random-hacker

Comment: Ah!  `int (* f [])()` can legally be used as a *function parameter* type, e.g. `void func(int (* f [])());`. In that particular case we don't need to specify the size of the innermost array dimension because array-to-pointer conversion takes place immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is quite valid, if you use initialization block. For [example](http://ideone.com/fzt1SX):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 0;
int a() { return x++ + 1; }
int b() { return x++ + 2; }
int c() { return x++ + 3; }

int main() 
{
  int (* abc[])() = {&a, &b, &c};
  int i = 0,
      l = sizeof(abc)/sizeof(abc[0]);
  for (; i < l; i++) { 
    printf("Give me a %d for %d!\n", (*abc[i])(), i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the second example is legal, since the size of the function array is not known, but what it is supposed to be is an array of function pointers, and here is a possible example of usage if the size would be known:

```
int a()
{
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc ,char** argv)
{
    int (* f [1])();
    f[0] = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`int f[]();` // this is illegal because of you can't create array of functions . It's illegal in `C`

But second is legal

`int (* f [])();` It says that f is an array of function pointers returning `int` and taking unspecified number of arguments

Comment: No, `[]` `()` `.` `->` are having same precedence and associativity is right to left

Comment: @Omkant: `int f[]()` is not illegal because of operator precedence, it's illegal because arrays of functions are an illegal type in C.  Note that (a) `int f[5][7]` is a legal type even though `[]` has the same evaluation order and precedence as `[]`; and (b) even if you define the type in two parts using `typedef`, the resulting type is still illegal: `typedef int temp_type(); temp_type g[5];`. -1.

Answer (score 1):

```
int f[]();  /* this one is illegal */
```

That's trying to declare an array of functions, which is impossible.

```
int (* f [])(); /* this one NOT legal, despite what the OP's post says. */
```

That's trying to declare an array of function *pointers*, which *would* be perfectly legal (and sensible) if the array size were specified, e.g.:

```
int (* f [42])(); /* this one legal. */
```

**EDIT:** The type `int (* f [])()` *can* be used as a function parameter type, because for function parameter types, array-to-pointer conversion takes place immediately, meaning we don't ever need to specify the dimension of the innermost array of a (possibly multidimensional) array:

```
void some_func(int (* f [])());  /* This is also legal. */
```